# Upper limit for volume in a sound file

Tags: speakers

All the speakers have a maximum limit which is the knob being rotated to the maximum.

But for music files the case is different.
We know that different sounds have different volumes levels. And every file represents it somehow by a list ones and zeros, encapsulated in the audio  itself.

Now as a result of that, you can always add more digits to represent this data, and theoretically it means you can get to any sound and volume you want, which probably isn't true.

So if speakers have a physical property that limits their volume, what happens in sound files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect on at least 2 levels, and when corrected  explains away the problem.

Different sounds do not have different levels, rather thesame sound can have different volumes.

While it would be correct that it's theoretically possible to represent almost any conceivable volume in a file, this is not done in practice. The typical way it's done is to sample the soundwave a certain number of times (more is better up to a certain point) and represent the height as a number. THE KEY IS THAT  THIS NUMBER is RELATIVE to "maximum volume". A greater range of numbers provide more accurate, but not louder sound.  It is possible, of-course to be less then the relative maximum to represent softer sounds.

If too much of the sound is loud, or if trying to represent more then the relative maximum, clipping and distortion occurs.

Comment: Who sets the maximum volume? The sound card? And what's the the difference  between raising the volume in the computer to raising it through the speakers?

Comment: The maximum volume is set by the sound card (and mixer on it I believe) - and this is typically constrained as per standards for the type of connection. (See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level for an overview).  Similarly the speakers expect a maximum volume and will amplify it. If there is to great a volume on the computer audio out this will overdrive the amplifier (pre-amp I imagine) in the speaker causing distortion. Raising the volume on the computer to 100% will usually give the most accurate output, as it maximises signs to noise ratio.

Comment: Perhaps another way to explain it is that any digital audio file is at any given time sending a signal that is a **percentage** of maximum output. It can never exceed 100% [unlike sportsmen who seem to feel 110% effort is mathematically possible ;) Note I haven't yet mentioned the word "volume". The volume itself comes from taking this signal & amplifying it; this depends entirely on separate circuitry, literally an amplifier [amp]. Some amps are barely powerful enough to make your phone speakers work, others can fill a stadium with sound.

Answer (score 0):

> All the speakers have a maximum limit which is the knob being rotated to the maximum.

You're conflating powered speakers (speaker with built-in amplifier) with (basic) speakers and drivers (the individual component that actually reproduces sound).
The "knob" would be part of a pre-amp stage, and essentially controls the amount of (electrical) power that would be delivered to the actual speaker(s).
The maximum or full power of the amplifier may or may not be sufficient to produce the maximum acoustical output of the speaker.

Hence you're starting with a faulty premise.

> But for music files the case is different.

Of course, because you're comparing apples to oranges.
A speaker is an electro-mechcanical device to reproduce sound.
A *"music file"* is part of a storage method.

> We know that different sounds have different volumes levels.

Maybe, or maybe not.
You really need to learn a lot more.
The two salient attributes of a *"sound"* are frequency and amplitude.

> And every file represents it somehow by a list ones and zeros, ...

Your lack of properly identifying the storage method (i.e. recording) is appalling.
Presumably you are referring to a digital recording, which is typically encoded rather than stored as raw data samples.
The salient attributes of a digital audio recording are sampling rate, sampling word size, and encoding.

> ... encapsulated in the audio itself.

It's naive to consider the sampled data the same thing as the sound.

> Now as a result of that, you can always add more digits to represent this data, and theoretically it means you can get to any sound and volume you want, which probably isn't true.

Is *"more digits"* supposed to mean more samples or larger word size?
Neither relates to more amplitude (i.e. louder), since all digital samples are relative to the maximum recording level.

> So if speakers have a physical property that limits their volume,

The physical properties that limit the maximum sound level (aka maxSPL) that can be reproduced depends on the driver technology, e.g. dynamic cone, electrostatic panel, etc.
For the ubiquitous cone the salient parameters are the cone area and excursion.

> ... what happens in sound files?

The *"sound levels"* in digital recordings are all relative to a maximum input level typically designated 0dB (i.e. zero deciBels).
The maximum acoustical loudness that could be recorded would be dictated by the microphones and electronics employed.
The recording engineer would/should apply the necessary attenuation (or gain) to the input signal so that the maximum signal during the recording will register as 0dB.

If the 0dB level is set higher than necessary, then the full dynamic range offered by the sampling word size is not utilized, and softer sounds will lose resolution.
If the 0dB level is set lower than required, then once loud sounds exhaust whatever headroom that is available, the recorded signal will clip.

So there is no "limit" to the loudest sound that can be recorded simply because the "maximum" sound is expected to be 0dB level.
To forestall any unexpected input louder than the 0dB level, modern recording techniques use compressors and limiters, usually a detriment to audio quality.